# Proceedural Code in Silex or maybe other Microframeworks

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, routes, silex

I'm taking an application I wrote, a form, and rewriting it in Silex. It was, for various reasons, written like:

- page1.php

  - page1_process.php
- page2.php

  - page2_process.php
- page3.php

  - page3_process.php

Where pageX.php is an HTML form with little PHP code, that passes data to the process script. The process script stores data to a Form object, and serializes the object in the Session.

Currently, I have the pageX.php pages as TWIG template files and they work, but I don't know how to incorporate the logic of the procedural process scripts.

I'm sure I don't copy the actual logic to the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow your requirements, you just need the same route twice: one for get (displaying the form) and one for post to handle it. In the post controller you just need to include your *pageX_process.php* and you should be ready to go.

Translated in Silex code it should be something like:

```
<?php
/**
 * if you're using silex-skeleton 
 * from: https://packagist.org/packages/fabpot/silex-skeleton)
 * this file should be src/controllers
 */

// standard setup, like error handling and other route declarations

$app->get('/page1', function() use ($app) {
   // you're currently using this (somehow)
  $params = []; //set up your template parameters here

  return $app['twig']->render('page1.twig', $params);
});

$app->post('/page1_proccess', function() use($app) {
  ob_start();
  require PATH_TO_LEGACY_FILES_DIR . '/page1_process.php';

  return ob_get_clean();
});
```

From now on, and if you want / find it adequate, you can start to refactor your *pageX_process.php* pages in a more OOP / Silex way, but you have a starting point with this application architecture.

NOTICE:

- you should move your php files away from the web directory (for example legacy/ in the root of your project)
- you must point your form handling script (the *action* parameter) to the new route (you can make it to work using the old route also but requires some little more effort)